# set cookie and show div on first visit then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I am trying to set multiple cookies depending on if the div exists via javascript but I have ran into an issue that I cannot figure out. On first visit, I would like to show the div to the user if the div exists then set a cookie (called *redCookie*) that expires in 3 days. After cookie is set on page refresh div should not be present. After 3 days I would like the div to be shown again  redDiv.show().

At the moment the div shows on all page refreshes. The cookie is set but unfortunately it shows every time. Something must be wrong with my if statement but not sure what.

**if ((redCookie = true) && (redDiv.length > 0))**

Here is a link to js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9uh96bh7/

Here are my functions:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    colourCookies();
});
function colourCookies () {
    var redCookie = getCookie("red-cookie-name");
    var redDiv = $('.red');
    var yellowCookie = getCookie("yellow-cookie-name");
    var yellowDiv = $('.yellow');

    if ((redCookie = true) && (redDiv.length > 0)) {
        redDiv.show();
        setCookie("red-cookie-name", redCookie, 3);
        console.log ('red cookie is set');
    } else {
        redDiv.hide();
    }
    if ((yellowCookie = true) && (yellowDiv.length > 0)) {
        yellowDiv.show();
        setCookie("yellow-cookie-name", yellowCookie, 3);
        console.log ('yellow cookie is set');
    } else {
        yellowDiv.hide();
    }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: you are assigning true value to redCookie by doing if ((redCookie = true) ... , change to if ((redCookie == true), as '=' is assignent operator

Comment: i have tried that, cookie is not set and div doesn't show up at all for me: jsfiddle.net/9uh96bh7/2

Answer (score 1):

First, the code.

It should be `if ((redCookie == true) && (redDiv.length > 0))` not `if ((redCookie = true) && (redDiv.length > 0))`.

`=` is assign, `==` means equal to.

Second, the logic part.

```
cookie isset -> hide div
cookie is not set -> show div, set cookie
(correct me if I miss understood.)
```

So the if statement should be:

```
if (redCookie == true){
    //hide div
} else {
    //show div
    //set cookie
}
```

Third, you make a mistake when setting cookies.
you should set you cookie like `setCookie("yellow-cookie-name", true, 3);`

If you use `setCookie("yellow-cookie-name", yellowCookie, 3);` and `yellowCookie` is `null`, this will cause failure to your if statement.

Comment: i have followed all your advices, still div shows up on each page load: https://jsfiddle.net/9uh96bh7/10/

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with setting cookie, as some of the browser like chrome not sets cookie when you are running it on local, if you host it on server or run it through visual studio, it will work.. Test once with hosting it in iis if possible, else you can use localStorage like below...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
colourCookies();
});
function colourCookies () { 

removeIfThreeDaysElapsed('red-ls');
removeIfThreeDaysElapsed('yellow-ls');

if (!localStorage.getItem('red-ls')) {
    $(".red").show();
    localStorage.setItem("red-ls", new Date().toGMTString());
} else {
    $(".red").hide();
}
if (!localStorage.getItem('yellow-ls')) {
    $(".yellow").show();
   localStorage.setItem("yellow-ls", new Date().toGMTString());
} else {
     $(".yellow").hide();
}
}

function removeIfThreeDaysElapsed(lsname){
  var d1 = localStorage.getItem(lsname);
  if(d1){
   if(new Date() > new Date(new Date().getTime()+(3*24*60*60*1000))){
   localStorage.removeItem(lsname);
   }
  }
}
```

You may need to edit the code to handle all the scenarios!

If you able to see the cookie in browser, then please try with check like below...

```
if (redCookie) {
    redDiv.hide();
} else {   
    redDiv.show();
    setCookie("red-cookie-name", true, 3);
}
```

Because when you are getting value back from cookie its datatype is not boolean, it gets converted to string, so either you check like above or can use `redCookie === "true"`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i can see that the cookie is set however the div shows up on each page refreshes

Comment: @replicant129 please check if edit above works for you!